# SQL: One column with different types, how to query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'll do my best to explain my issue, however most of my experience in SQL is self taught, so please bear with me.

I have a table [limit_table] which has a column called [amount], however this limit_table.amount column holds an amount but is for different limit types, the limit type is determined by the a column called LimitTypeid, which has a foreign-key link to another table [LimitType]

The limit_table also has a foreign key link to a [client] table.

What i am trying to do is to get the limit for each client in the [client] table where the LimitType = x out of those results i also want to know if the client as LimitType of y even if it doesn't exist.

For the life of me i can't get this to work? Any pointers would be great I have tried joining/left outer joining back into the client table using the `client.id` from the client table, but this didn't seem to work.

So LimitType X must be present (can be zero but not NULL) but LimitType y is optional.

Hoping to end with results that look basically like

```
Client   LimitTypeXAmount   LimitTypeYAmount
ClientA  15000.00           1000.00
ClientB  10000.00           NULL
ClientC  0                  1000.00
```

Here is a previous query i tried:

```
SELECT CL.CLIENT, LIM.AMOUNT AS LIMITTYPEXAMOUNT, LIM2.AMOUNT AS LIMITTYPEYAMOUNT, FROM CLIENT CL1 
INNER JOIN LIMIT LIM1 ON LIM1.CLIENTID = CL1.ID
INNER JOIN LIMITTYPE LT1 ON LIM1.LIMITTYPEID = LT1.ID AND LT1.TYPE = 'X'
LEFT OUTER JOIN CLIENT CL2 ON CL1.ID = CL2.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN LIMIT LIM2 ON LIM2.CLIENTID = CL2.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN LIMITTYPE LT2 ON LIM2.LIMITTYPEID = LT2.ID AND LT2.TYPE = 'Y'
```

Presumed schema below (added by moderator):

```
create table Client (Id int not null, Client varchar(10) not null);
create table Limit (Id int not null, ClientId int not null, Amount decimal (8, 2) not null, LimitTypeId int not null);
create table LimitType (Id int not null, Type char(1) not null);

insert into LimitType (Id, Type) values (1, 'X'), (2, 'Y');
insert into Client (Id, Client) values (1, 'ClientA'), (2, 'ClientB'), (3, 'ClientC');
insert into Limit (Id, ClientId, Amount, LimitTypeId) values
    (1, 1, 15000.00, 1), (2, 1, 1000.00, 2), -- ClientA  15000.00    1000.00
    (3, 2, 10000.00, 1),                     -- ClientB  10000.00       NULL
    (4, 3,     0.00, 1), (5, 3, 1000.00, 2)  -- ClientC      0.00    1000.00
;
```

Comment: CASE statement and sub queries will do the work

Comment: Before asking question, learn how to ask question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Also what have you tried so far?????  SO is not a free coding service.  You post your query, we can help make it work..

Comment: Thanks Eric, i am aware this isn't a free coding service, which is why i was asking for pointers, not asking someone to write a query for me.

Comment: @AlanThomas - please provide full schema of the tables in question.

Comment: Which dbms is this????  The syntax is different from one dbms to another.

Comment: @STLDeveloper The tables i given are faux  tables as the full database schema is massive, the key constraints on the above faux tables are the same as the real tables

This is SQL Server

Comment: Please add SQL Server tag.

Comment: The desired results are good here, but some sample data in your two tables would be very helpful so we can best understand how to get from your sample data to your desired results, using your attempted SQL and description as a guide. It's difficult to reverse engineer just desired results and a failed attempt. Your whole schema isn't necessary, just the handful of fields in the two tables and a few sample records that correspond to the desired results you have shared.

Comment: Since you haven't included a reasonable schema to help illustrate/explain your question, I'm voting to close it as "unclear what you're asking".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why you have the `LIMITTYPE` table. I'm assuming there's only one row in that table with `TYPE = 'Y'`. So connecting to that as an inner join first should pull in just that one row and then you can link to the appropriate `LIMITTYPEID`. What I'm unclear about is why `TYPE` isn't just an attribute of `LIMIT`. You were referencing two different instances of the `CLIENT` table but that appears to be unnecessary and I removed it.

```
select
c.Client, l1.Amount as LimitTypeXAmount, l2.Amount as LimitTypeYAmount
from
    Client c
    inner join Limit as l1 on l1.ClientId = c.Id
    inner join LimitType as lt1 on lt1.Id = l1.LimitTypeId and lt1.Type = 'X'
    inner join LimitType as lt2 on lt2.Type = 'Y'
    left outer join Limit as l2 on l2.ClientId = c.Id and l2.LimitTypeId = lt2.Id;
```

Assuming that works you could mirror that same logic in the earlier three joins. I'll leave those alone.

Another approaches uses a derived table:

```
-- derived table
SELECT
    C.CLIENT,
    L1.AMOUNT AS LIMITTYPEXAMOUNT,
    L2.LIMITTYPEYAMOUNT
FROM 
    CLIENT C 
    INNER JOIN LIMIT L1 ON L1.CLIENTID = C.ID
    INNER JOIN LIMITTYPE LT1 ON LT1.ID = L1.LIMITTYPEID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT
            L.CLIENTID, L.AMOUNT AS LIMITTYPEYAMOUNT
        FROM 
            LIMIT L
            INNER JOIN LIMITTYPE LT ON LT.ID = L.LIMITTYPEID
        WHERE
            LT.TYPE = 'Y'
    ) AS L2 ON L2.CLIENTID = C.ID
WHERE
    LT1.TYPE = 'X';
```

And just for fun, with `outer apply`:

```
-- outer apply
SELECT
    C.CLIENT,
    L1.AMOUNT AS LIMITTYPEXAMOUNT,
    L2.LIMITTYPEYAMOUNT
FROM 
    CLIENT C 
    INNER JOIN LIMIT L1 ON L1.CLIENTID = C.ID
    INNER JOIN LIMITTYPE LT1 ON LT1.ID = L1.LIMITTYPEID
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT
            L.AMOUNT AS LIMITTYPEYAMOUNT
        FROM 
            LIMIT L
            INNER JOIN LIMITTYPE LT ON LT.ID = L.LIMITTYPEID
        WHERE
            LT.TYPE = 'Y' AND L.CLIENTID = C.ID
    ) AS L2
WHERE
    LT1.TYPE = 'X';
```

Edit: I guess I'm a little rusty since I didn't also immediately recognize this as a join order problem. Here's another approach you can study. It has the advantage of working on some older systems where other options aren't available.

```
select
    c.Client, l1.Amount as LimitTypeXAmount, l2.Amount as LimitTypeYAmount
from
    Client c
    inner join Limit as l1
        inner join LimitType as lt1
            on lt1.Id = l1.LimitTypeId and lt1.Type = 'X'
        on l1.ClientId = c.Id

    left outer join Limit as l2
        inner join LimitType as lt2
            on l2.LimitTypeId = lt2.Id and lt2.Type = 'Y'    
        on l2.ClientId = c.Id;
```

Play with it here: http://rextester.com/WJZ23471

Comment: These were exactly what i was after, and gave me a point in right direction, i seem to be getting what i want. - Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Your query doesn't seem wrong. Fix the typo `LIM.AMOUNT` to `LIM1.AMOUNT`. The second Client table is useless: `LEFT OUTER JOIN CLIENT CL2`, you could delete that line and replace `CL2` by `CL1` everywhere else.